# UIView constraints causing issues

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview

I have a camera app that uses a uiview to take the photo. When not using constraints the uiview fills its area only leaving a small amount of background color on the left and right sides. However when I put constraints on the uiview and run it on my iPad this happens as you can see the uiveiw is not using all of the area. [image: UIVEIW WITH CONSTRAINTS IN IPAD]

```
 import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate  {

var captureSesssion : AVCaptureSession!
var cameraOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

@IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
        if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSesssion.addInput(input)
            if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
                previewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)




                captureSesssion.startRunning()
            }
        } else {
            print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
        }
    } else {
        print("some problem here")
    }
}


@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
    ]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)




    }



    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,  previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings:  AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings:   AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)


            self.capturedImage.image = image


            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
        } else {
            print("some error here")
        }
    }


    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved!", message: "Your image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
func askPermission() {
    print("here")
    let cameraPermissionStatus =  AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    switch cameraPermissionStatus {
    case .authorized:
        print("Already Authorized")
    case .denied:
        print("denied")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry :(" , message: "But  could you please grant permission for camera within device settings",  preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel,  handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case .restricted:
        print("restricted")
    default:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: {
            [weak self]
            (granted :Bool) -> Void in

            if granted == true {
                // User granted
                print("User granted")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                    //Do smth that you need in main thread   
                } 
            }
            else {
                // User Rejected
                print("User Rejected")

                DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WHY?" , message:  "Camera it is the main feature of our application", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)  
                } 
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing **what** constraints you're using, but....  Try Xcode's View Debugging feature to see your layout at run time.  It will show the constraints are being used and how they affect your views.

Comment: I am justing using select all views in view controller and applying the suggested constraints. @PhillipMills

Comment: Auto Layout also uses size classes for differentiating between the screen sizes for iPhone and iPad. Check that too. Read more about Auto-Layout. Your best bet would be keeping the view sticking to the screen edges (constant leading and trailing edges, horizontal and vertical centering etc)

Comment: It would work perfectly if it was just a iPhone app but since its both iPad and iPhone that is what is screwing this up. @PhillipMills; @sagarU

Comment: @PhillipMills and I have uploaded all of my text does that do anything